# What is the use of 'isset' in PHP?

Tags: php

`if (isset($_GET['user_name']) && !empty($_GET['user_name']))`

In the above code what is the use of the part - `(isset($_GET['user_name'])`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: to check that value is set or not

Comment: Read [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: google is your friend

Answer (score 2):

`isset` will check if `$_GET['user_name']` is **set and is not NULL**. But if you are using `!empty($_GET['user_name'])`, there is no need for `isset()` as `empty()` will take care of it.

Only `if (!empty($_GET['user_name']))` will check if `$_GET['user_name']` is set and it contains a value.

**NOTE:** `empty()` will return `true` for -

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) & [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)